# Trouble with OpenStack Ceilometer client

Tags: python, notifications, openstack, alarms, ceilometer

I try to get meters and notifications from OpenStack. For this purpose I want to use Ceilometer (via ceilometerclient). I wrote some code to test these possibilities.

```
import keystoneclient.v2_0
import ceilometerclient.v2 as ceilometer

class CloudMessageHandler(object):

def __init__(self, params):

    self._client = None
    self._auth_data = self._get_token(params["auth"])
    try:
        print "auth_data = %s" % repr(self._auth_data)
        self._client = ceilometer.Client(endpoint=self._auth_data['endpoint'],
                                         token=self._auth_data['token'])
    except:
        raise Exception("Can't create Ceilometer client.")

def _get_token(self, params):
    try:
        ksclient = keystoneclient.v2_0.Client(username=params["username"],
                                              password=params["password"],
                                              tenant_id=params["tenant_id"],
                                              tenant_name=params["tenant_name"],
                                              auth_url=params["auth_url"])
        token = ksclient.auth_token
        endpoint = ksclient.service_catalog.url_for(service_type="metering",
                                                    endpoint_type=params["endpoint_type"])
        return { "token" : token, "endpoint" : endpoint }
    except IndexError as e:
        raise Exception("Can't get token and endpoint through Keystone API.")

def test(self):
    print "meters = %s" % self._client.meters.list()
    print "resources = %s" % self._client.resources.list()
    print "alarms = %s" % self._client.alarms.list()
```

Output that I get:

```
auth_data = {'token': u'xxx', 'endpoint': u'http://ip:port'}
meters = []
resources = []
No handlers could be found for logger "ceilometerclient.common.http"
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometerclient/v2/alarms.py", line 53, in     list
     return self._list(options.build_url(self._path(), q))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometerclient/common/base.py", line 57, in _list
     resp, body = self.api.json_request('GET', url)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometerclient/common/http.py", line 182, in json_request
     resp, body_iter = self._http_request(url, method, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometerclient/common/http.py", line 165, in _http_request
    raise exc.from_response(resp)
 ceilometerclient.exc.HTTPNotFound: HTTPNotFound (HTTP 404)
```

What's wrong? I also can't create alarms.
Can anybody give me an example how I can get notifications about an instance (run/terminate events) via Ceilometer client?

Answer (score 1):

I try to debug horizon ,

```
from ceilometerclient.v2 import Client as ceil_client
from keystoneclient.v2_0.client import Client as KC


def get_token():
    kc = KC(username="admin", password="111111", tenant_name="admin", auth_url="http://192.168.176.101:5000/v2.0")
    token = kc.service_catalog.catalog['token']['id']
    return token

ceil = ceil_client(endpoint='http://XXX.XXX.XXX.:8777', token=get_token)
```

It works!
the horizon use endpoint port is 8777,I dont't knoe what you used,may be it will help you!